# Is there any limitation inside the Lookup field in one to many relation

Tags: office365, dataverse

We have a `Tasks` table which contain around 10,000 records, and `Customers` table which contain around 250 records. We built a `Many to Many` relation between the 2 tables. Then inside a canvas app we will show 2 drop-downs:

- `Customers`
- `Tasks`

So, the user can relate the related `Customers` with the related `Task`. Can the drop-down inside a canvas app show 10,000 items for the tasks? Or I will get a threshold error (sorry I am coming from a `SharePoint` :( ).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default limit for the number of items that can be displayed in a dropdown or lookup field is `500` items. However, this limit can be increased to a maximum of `2,000` items by modifying the settings in the `Power Apps` admin center.

In your case with `Tasks` table of more than `2,000` items, it is better to implement filtering or search functionality to limit the number of items displayed at once to avoid performance issues.

Comment: but what if i do not have any filtering ,, and i want the user to do the filtering at runtime, and on the same side i have 10,000 records inside the lookup?

Comment: Check out the workarounds provided in [this](https://michalguzowski.pl/how-to-overcome-500-items-limit-in-powerapps/) for large dataset.